# SQL Join excel vba

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run the following SQL query in access VBA and I am getting a join error.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I'm sure there's something obvious I am just overlooking.

```
SELECT a.LateDate, a.LateAgent, a.LateTime, b.PBXID,
       (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.Surname) as FullName
from tblLateLog a
    INNER Join tblAgents b on a.LateAgent = FullName
```

Comment: Can you add on your question what the error is?

Comment: You can't use column aliases in the ON clause. Do `ON a.LateAgent = (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.Surname)`.

Comment: Please remove the excel-vba tag as this isn't anything to do with Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.LateDate, a.LateAgent, a.LateTime, b.PBXID,
       (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.Surname) as FullName
from tblLateLog a
    INNER Join tblAgents b ON a.LateAgent = (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.Surname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias in the same context of your query to do a join. Do as this:

```
SELECT a.LateDate, a.LateAgent, a.LateTime, b.PBXID,
       (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.Surname) as FullName
  FROM tblLateLog a
     INNER Join tblAgents b on a.LateAgent = (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.Surname)
```